# It's possible to get coordinates from google maps api v3 from biostall of an "onclick" created marker?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

i was wondering if its posible to do something like this:

http://wisteriahill.sakura.ne.jp/GMAP/GMAP_MARKER_E/

with google maps api v3 from biostall for codeigniter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an event listener to detect when you've clicked the map.

The `map` variable is your google.maps.Map instance!!

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
  alert('Latitude: ' + event.latLng.lat() + ' ' + ', Longitude: ' + event.latLng.lng()); 
});
```

...or you could just look at the source of the site you have referenced and see how they do it!!

```
http://wisteriahill.sakura.ne.jp/GMAP/GMAP_MARKER_E/g_script.js
```

Hope that helps!!